# Can I measure the volume of a locked room by pumping gas through keyhole and measuring its entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Suppose that I have a locked room and a keyhole in the door and I want to measure the room's volume.

Suppose also that I have some "magical" "artificial" inert gas A that doesn't interact with anything but "artificial" substance B and both of them never exist in nature. Substance B is solid and mounted on a surface. Interaction of gas A with substance B is thermodynamically beneficial and has energy E per molecule. So, when temperature is low, all the gas A is absorbed on surface B. I start to gradually increase the temperature. When it gets very high, A will dissociate from B due to entropy summand and take the volume of the room.

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I quantitatively calculate the fraction of A, absorbed by B upon current temperature?
2. Does phase transition between states AB and A + B happen almost abruptly upon certain temperature or does concentration of free gaseous A increase gradually?
3. If transition is abrupt, how can I calculate the temperature, upon which it happens?
4. The larger the room, the easier it is for A to dissociate from B? How to calculate the dependence between room Volume and Entropy?

Comment: Related to measuring entropy: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129158/how-to-measure-entropy

Comment: What's wrong with simply applying the ideal gas law? Your method sounds a little bit like a Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: @CuriousOne How would you measure the room's volume with ideal gas law, if there are other gases in the room? Also, here I'm speaking of a room, but same approach might be related to solution.

Comment: The partial pressure of an ideal gas does not depend on what else is in the room, that includes other gases. At most you have to wait many diffusion times to get that ideal gas spread out in the entire volume, but equilibrium thermodynamics doesn't care about how long it takes to achieve equilibrium.